# Resque require 'csv' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I am using resque to process a file in the background. It's a CSV file however I get the following error: `uninitialized constant ImportFileHelper::CSV`

I have tried to `require 'csv'` and also `include CSV` neither will work.

```
require 'csv'

module ImportFileHelper  
  HOST = ""
  USER_NAME = ""
  PASSWORD = ""

  def self.process_file(file_data, file_name)
    init
    @file_name = file_name
    begin
      csv = CSV.parse(file_data, :headers => true)
      csv.each do |row|
        @first_name = row["FirstName"]
        @last_name = row["LastName"]
        @email = row["Email"]
        @password = "ch@ngeM3!"
        @user_group_name = row["GroupName"].split(",")
        @store_name = row["StoreName"]
        @external_id = row["ExternalID"]

        add_user unless @first_name.nil? || @last_name.nil? || @email.nil? || @password.nil? || @first_name.empty? || @last_name.empty? || @email.empty?
      end
    rescue NoMethodError => no_method_error
      log_error_to_db no_method_error
    rescue IOError => error
      log_error_to_db error
      @errors << error.to_s
    rescue Exception => ex
      log_error_to_db ex
    end
    prep_soap_responses_for_output
  end

  def self.init
    HTTPI.log = false
    @body = { username: USER_NAME, password: PASSWORD }
    @errors = []
    @existing_users = []

    configure_savon
    get_all_groups
    get_all_stores
  end

  def self.prep_soap_responses_for_output
    [@existing_users, @errors]
  end

  def self.log_error_to_db(error)
    error.backtrace ||= "Not Available"
    if error.message.length > 250
      error_message = "There was an error"
    else
      error_message = error.message
    end
    ErrorLog.create(message: error_message, trace: error.backtrace, file_name: @file_name)
  end

  def self.get_store_id
    @store_id = @stores[@store_name.to_sym]
  end

  def self.get_all_stores
    @stores = {  }
    client = Savon::Client.new(HOST + "Storews.asmx?wsdl")
    body_data = { mall_id: 1, is_return_offline_store: :false }
    @body.merge! body_data

    begin
      response = client.request :get_store_list, body: @body

      if response
        hash_response = response.to_hash
        stores = hash_response[:get_store_list_response][:get_store_list_result][:store]

        stores.each do |s|
          store = { s[:name].to_sym => s[:store_id] }
          @stores.merge! store
        end
      end
    rescue Savon::Error => ex
      log_error_to_db error
      @errors << error.to_s
    end
  end

  def self.create_adbuilder_user_object
    AdbuilderUser.new(@first_name, @last_name, @email, @user_id, @store_id, @store_name, @user_group_name, @group_id, @external_id)
  end

  def self.configure_savon
    Savon.configure do |configure|
      configure.log = false
    end
  end

  def self.add_user
    body_data = { first_name: @first_name, last_name: @last_name, user_password: @password, email: @email, external_id: @external_id }
    @body.merge! body_data
    begin
      client = Savon::Client.new(HOST + "UserWS.asmx?wsdl")
      response = client.request :add_user, body: @body
      if response
        @user_id = response.body[:add_user_response][:add_user_result]

        if @user_group_name
          get_group_id
        end

        if @store_name
          @store_id = get_store_id
          unless @store_id.to_s =~ /^0$/
            adbuilder_user = create_adbuilder_user_object
            UserMailer.create_password(adbuilder_user).deliver if adbuilder_user
          end
        end
      end
    rescue Savon::Error => error
      log_error_to_db error

      if error.message == "(soap:Client) 3: A user with the same email login already exists. Please choose a different login."
        @existing_users << @email
      else
        @errors << error.to_s
      end
    rescue Exception => error
      log_error_to_db error
      @errors << error.message.to_s
    end
  end

  def self.get_group_id
    begin
      @user_group_name.each do |group_name|
        user_group_id = @groups_info[group_name.downcase.to_sym]
        add_user_to_group user_group_id if user_group_id
      end
    rescue Exception => error
      log_error_to_db error
      @errors << error.message.to_s
    end
  end

  def self.get_all_groups
    @groups_info = {}
    begin
      client = Savon::Client.new(HOST + "Usergroupws.asmx?wsdl")
      response = client.request :get_user_group_list, body: @body
      if response
        group = response.to_hash
        groups = group[:get_user_group_list_response][:get_user_group_list_result][:user_group]

        groups.each do |g|
          new_hash = { g[:name].gsub(/\s/, "_").downcase.to_sym => g[:user_group_id] }
          @groups_info.merge! new_hash
        end
      end
    rescue Savon::Error => error
      log_error_to_db
      @errors << error.to_s
    end
  end

  def self.add_user_to_group(group_id)
    body_data = { user_id: @user_id, user_group_id: group_id }
    @body.merge! body_data
    begin
      client = Savon::Client.new(HOST + "Usergroupws.asmx?wsdl")
      response = client.request :add_user_to_group, body: @body
    rescue Savon::Error => error
      log_error_to_db error
      @errors << error.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

So as a work around for this I am doing the csv parsing in the resque job file. This is now allowing it to run. Not sure if this is the best way to do it though.

```
class ProcessFile
  @queue = :rts_file_parser

  def self.perform(file_data, file_name)
    csv = CSV.parse(file_data, :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|
      row_data = { first_name: row["FirstName"], last_name: row["LastName"], email: row["Email"], password: "ch@ngeM3!", user_group_name: row["GroupName"].split(","), store_name: row["StoreName"], external_id: row["ExternalID"] }

      ImportFileHelper.process_file file_name, row_data
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The full code file where you're running into the error.

Comment: Could it be a problem with scope resolution? Try `::CSV.parse` instead of `CSV.parse`.

Comment: Just 2 things to check: 1. your module name is `ImportFileHelper` whereas the error says `ImportFileHelper::CSV`, might be the naming issue?2. Is this file in autoload path(assuming lib folder), you might want to verify that in application.rb. And yes, full code where you call this module will be helpful as @rudolph has said.

Comment: So `ImportFileHelper` is in app/helpers

Comment: @covard did you try removing `require csv` from top and write this line inside the module `include csv` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mind if I claim the answer (via my comment)?

It looks like it might be a scope resolution issue.

Try `::CSV` instead of `CSV`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the gem to the gemfile.